# News Item Ctegorization

Tags: java, text, methods, classification, categories

I want to implement a method in java that could be used to categorize some news items taken from an RSSFeed, which's descriptions are with no more than 30 words, into categories like Politics, Economic, Weather, ..etc. How could I get some start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Classifier4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classifier4j/) library. Here is a short [tutorial](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/usage.html).

Comment: I downloaded the Jar file. But is there anyway I could have some knowledge for using this library. Like a tutorial or something I could refer?